# Python android How to set text to Clipboard and share links

Tags: python, android, hyperlink

I need a way to share a link or copy it to clipboard

```
import clipboard
clipboard.copy("abc")  
text = clipboard.paste()
```

Error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in                                           start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)                File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start                                             exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  **main**.**dict**)                                         File "", line 2, in           File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyperclip/**init**.py", line 615, in lazy_load_stub_copy                                      copy, paste = determine_clipboard()         File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyperclip/**init**.py", line 509, in determine_clipboard                                      with open('/proc/version', 'r') as f:     PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/proc/version'                              [Program finished]

Comment: The code in this question seems to be copied from the front page of https://pypi.org/project/clipboard/ . Did you install the library? Did you try the code? What problem did you have?

Comment: It's not working.![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCjqJ.jpg)

Comment: Please include any errors you are having as formatted text in your question, not links to pictures of text in your comments.

Comment: @khelwood can you help me